# sails many to many associations failing to save

Tags: save, many-to-many, sails.js, waterline

My sails many to many associations have stopped saving changes, that is, if I deselect one of the items in my checkbox list, or select a new one, the changes are not saved (populated to the join table).

It used to work, although I am not sure how long it's been broken for.

All the other fields on the page save correctly.

So I know the mechanics of most of it are correct, just the many to many associations, ie, updating the list of active records in the join table.

Any hints on what I can be doing wrong in my save?

I have the following models:

```
/**
* User.js
*/

module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        projects: {
            collection: 'project',
            via: 'users'
        },
    }

/**
* Project.js
*/

module.exports = {

attributes: {
    users: {
        collection: 'user',
        via: 'projects',
        dominant: true
    },
}
```

In my form I am returning a checkbox list like such

```
{ projectname: 'AS Story Database',
  userlist: [ '10', '3', '1' ], <-- this line is the many to many line from the check boxs
  projecttype: 'Development',
  companyid: '1',
  startdate: 'Sat Jan 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)',
  enddate: '' }
}
```

I tried populating the result set

```
Project.findOne({'id':id})
    .populate('users') <--------- heres the populate I added but didnt seem to have effect
    .exec(function(err,project){
```

This is the save dialog in my sails controller

```
var a=req.param('project',null);
    console.log(a); <-- note this is where the json above is output
    project.projecttype= a.projecttype,
    project.projectname= a.projectname,
    project.companyid= a.companyid,
    project.users= a.userlist, <-- this is the many to many association that used to work
    project.startdate = a.startdate,
    project.enddate = a.enddate

    project.save(function(err,updated){ <-- here is the save function
        if (err) {
            req.session.flash = {'err':err};
            sails.controllers.project.edit(req,res);
        }else{
            req.session.flash = {};
            res.redirect('project/index');
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are assigning array to `project.users` variable instead of using [`.add()`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values/add)/[`.remove()`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values/remove). Did it ever work this way?

Comment: Yes it did!
According to the docs this is the way its supposed to work.
Although I am coming to the conclusion I need to write a deep update mechanism myself.

Comment: Can you please provide link to doc which tells `project.users` can be directly assigned to an array?

Answer (score 1):

@Sangharsh is correct in his comment above; you cannot update a collection by assigning an array to it and calling `.save()`.  You may be thinking of `.update()`, which in Sails v0.12.x allows you to provide an array of objects to replace the existing set (although this has been removed in Sails 1.0 since it caused a lot of bugs and confusion).

The correct way to update an existing instance's collection in Sails v0.12.x is to use the [`.add()`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values/add) and [`.remove()`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values/remove) methods.  See the [many-to-many associations doc page](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many) for more info.

In Sails 1.0, the `.save()` method of individual records has been removed to make things clearer; you always use the [`.addToCollection()`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/reference/waterline/models/addToCollection.md), [`.removeFromCollection()`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/reference/waterline/models/removeFromCollection.md) and [`.replaceCollection()`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/reference/waterline/models/replaceCollection.md) model class methods to manipulate plural associations.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was lulled into a false sense of security by the fact it actually seemed to work at first.

Comment: It looks like the .replaceCollection() function is what I want in this instance.

I thought the assign the variable with an array was a bit easy, and I was surprised it worked in the first instance.

This is the working version (untested but should work):
Project.replaceCollection(project.id, 'users', a.userlist)

Answer (score -1):

Ok; I finally figured this out.
The method above (replaceCollection) only works on the older (0.x) versions of sails.

To get it working in the modern version, use

```
<model>.update('id':<the recordID>},{'<association name>':<list of new records>})
.exec(function(err,updated){
    -do something-
});
```

ie -

```
Project.update({'id':id},{'users': a.userlist}).exec(function(err,updated){
    project.save(function(err,updated){
        //console.log(updated);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            req.session.flash = {'err':err};
            sails.controllers.project.edit(req,res);
        }else{
            req.session.flash = {};
            res.redirect('project/index');
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: This is backwards.  `replaceCollection` is not available in versions of Sails <= 0.12.x, and `.save()` doesn't exist at all in Sails 1.0.  You may be getting mixed up between the version of Sails installed in your project, and your global Sails version.

Comment: What you have above should work in Sails v0.12.x, but the `.save()` is unnecessary; it's not doing anything.  The `.update()` call may work, but it's highly recommended that you not rely on "nested" updates like this, because the results can be different depending on what kind of items you have in that `userlist` array (i.e. whether they're just primary key values or whole object).  You're encouraged instead to retrieve the item with `.findOne().populate()` and then use `.users.add()` and `.users.remove()` to manipulate the collection, and then use `.save()` to persist it.